# Increase and decrease onclick like facebook like button

Tags: jquery

I would like to know how to create a like button in which the count will increase on first click and then decrease on the next click using jQuery.

Comment: Tried any thing?

Comment: can you provide some code here, so we can look into the issue.

Comment: $("#like").click(function(){
        num = parseInt($("#inc").text());
        $("#inc").text(num+1);
        $(this).css({"color": "#007aff", "pointer-events": "none"});
    });

Answer (score 1):

You can try this code. This does not save the "likes". To have that you have to use some backend langauge like PHP and a database to store the information in.

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
  $('a.button').click(function () {
  if ($(this).hasClass('clicked')) {
    $(this).removeClass('clicked');
    $(this).find('span.number').html(parseInt($(this).find('span.number').html()) - 1);
    $(this).find('span.label').html('Like');
  }
  else {
    $(this).addClass("clicked");$(this).find('span.number').html(parseInt($(this).find('span.number').html()) + 1);
    $(this).find('span.label').html('Dislike');
  }
});
});
```

```css
a.button {
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: #8b9dc3;
  padding: 4px 8px 4px 8px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  color: #3b5998;
  font-family: Arial;
  cursor: pointer;
  user-select: none;
}
a.button:hover {
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 3px grey;
}
a.button span.number {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-right: 5px;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a class="button"><span class="number">0</span><span class="label">Like</span></a>
```